# Should liaison ever be applied to the endings of conjugated verbs?

Tags: liaisons

I know the rule for liaison in compound verb construction is in between auxiliary and verb, such as 'je suis all/e', where the s at the end of suis would be pronounced. What if it were in the case of a simpler verb, such as choisir - choisis? The only reason I'm asking is that I have never heard anyone pronounce the s at the end of choisis in any setting. For instance, 'Tu choisis un livre'. I can't really think of an application for such a weird sentence in that I would probably use 'es en train de choisir', but hypothetically in this case, would we perform a liaison on 'choisis un', or would this s stay silent? Thanks in advance

Comment: Il est en retard, je suis à Rome, nous avons eu beaucoup de chance : liaison facultative dans chaque cas.

Comment: In the interrogative: *choisit-il ...?* there is a mandatory liaison. For *il choisit un ...,* it's technically an optional liaison, but it's an optional liaison that hardly anybody makes today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This liaison is optional and most people including me won't perform it.

Note: ***Tu choisis un livre*** is not a weird sentence.

> Au début de chaque projet, tu choisis un livre, n'importe lequel : tu n'as qu'à te laisser guider par ton inspiration, tes goûts du moment ou encore par le thème du projet en cours.

Françoise Dulude, *Signet : français : 5e année*, 1998.